# Print document without open the dialog box in C#

Tags: printing, doc

I have created a scheduler that print number of document in a day, i want to print these document silently(without opening the printer),

Can any one help me how to print document in c# without opening the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
doc.Print();
```